# event not working when element reached top

Tags: jquery

i want my navigation to animate from top when i scroll a "ghost" or helper div to window top. i used this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(".ghost").offset().top;
    var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollY >= y) {
      $("nav").animate({margin-top: "-50px"}, 750);



    }
      else{
       $("nav").animate({margin-top: "0px"}, 750);


      }

});
```

but this does not bring desired result. When ghost div reaches top, the there is no effect on nav. fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/e8Xj4/
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  $("nav").animate({margin-top: "-50px"}, 750);
```

to

```
  $("nav").animate({marginTop: "-50px"}, 750);
```

or

```
  $("nav").animate({"margin-top": "-50px"}, 750);
```

From [jQuery's CSS documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) :

> jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of
>   multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns
>   the correct value for both .css( "background-color" ) and .css(
>   "backgroundColor" ).